# Is title() an automatic method of a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods

I ask this question out of curiosity. I am reading Python's `Classes` from the book PYTHON CRASH COURSE (pp.162-163), where the author gives this example of a `Car` class:

```
class Car:
    """A simple attempt to represnt a car."""

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        """Initializae attributes to describe a car."""
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        """Return a neatly formatted descriptive name."""
        long_name = f"{self.year} {self.make} {self.model}"
        return long_name.title()

my_new_car = Car('audi', 'a4', 2019)
print(my_new_car.get_descriptive_name())
```

At first I was shocked to see `get_descriptive_name` method returns `long_name.title()`, so I assume it was a typo. Surprisingly, when I run this class it works:

```
$python car.py 
2019 Audi A4
```

But there's no description of where `title()` comes from. Can someone explain this?

Comment: No, it's a built-in `str` class method.

Comment: ... and `long_name` is a string.

Comment: Ah, I see the logic.

Answer (score 1):

`long_name` is a string. It has nothing to do with the `Car` class.

`title` is a method of `str`:

```
>>> help(str.title)
Help on method_descriptor:

title(self, /)
    Return a version of the string where each word is titlecased.

    More specifically, words start with uppercased characters and all remaining
    cased characters have lower case.
```

Or on the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title).

Or by `print`ing `long_name.title` (with no `()`):

```
<built-in method title of str object at 0x00B54BE0>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, `title()` is not an automatic method of Python classes, it is, however, a method of the `str` class. You may see this by using the `help()` builtin:

```py
help(str.title)

# Or you can call help() on an instantiated object
help(long_name.title)
```

```
Help on method_descriptor:

title(self, /)
    Return a version of the string where each word is titlecased.
    
    More specifically, words start with uppercased characters and all remaining
    cased characters have lower case.
```